# How to replace by NA the unknown factors for lm model in R?

Tags: r, lm

I have a lm model that is trained on some database and I want to predict some values for another database. The problem is that in the 'other' database, there are some factors that were not in the training database. I would like to replace those by NA values, so when predicting I'll get a NA value, too (I know that using `predict` with `na.action = na.exclude` it will do it).

Because I have not the training database, I can extract the known factors from the model like this: `model$xlevels[1] # contains the first factor values`. It is a list, and if I want to get the name of the factor I will use `names(model$xlevels[1])`. So now I want to get just the lines that contain the known factors:

```
knownData <- subset(allData, names(model$xlevels[1]) %in% model$xlevels[1])
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in model$xlevels : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

So I have split it like this:

```
factorName <- names(model$xlevels[2])
factorValues <- model$xlevels[2]
knownData <- subset(allData, factorName %in% factorValues)
```

And now I get an empty `knownData` (0 rows), even if there are many known factors.

I went deeper, so I have done

```
allData[factorName] %in% factorValues
[1] FALSE
```

It seems that there is only a single value and it is false.
How to extract the known data? Or better: How to replace the unknown factors by `NA`s?

---

**EDIT:**

I think that the problem is about the interpretation of the values, because if I do

```
allData$clnm %in% factorValues
```

I get just FALSE...

I have tried to interpret it as a factor

```
allData$clnm %in% as.factor(factorValues)
```

but not working, I am getting an error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

---

**Adding code for reproducibility**
Ok, just for having reproducibility, this is the code:

```
trnData = read.csv("http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/politeness_data.csv")
model <- lm(frequency ~ attitude + scenario, trnData)

tstData <- rbind(c("H1", "H", 2, "pol", 185),
                 c("M1", "M", 1, "pol", 115),
                 c("F1", "F", 3, "ang", 210))
colnames(tstData) <- colnames(allData)
tstData <- as.data.frame(tstData)
```

Supposing that we do not know the `trnData`, we can extract the values and the names for the used factors in training from:

```
factorName <- names(model$xlevels[1])
factorValues <- model$xlevels[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to post a reproducible example, otherwise we are guessing!! Look at this example and see if solves your problem.

```
n=50
set.seed(123)
d=data.frame(o=rnorm(n,10,3),t=1:n,w=rep(c("A","B","C"),length.out=n))
m=10
td=data.frame(o=rnorm(m,10,3),t=(n+1):(m+n),w=c("D","E",rep(c("A","B","C"),length.out=m-2)))

model <- lm(o ~ t * w,data=d)

cbind(td$o,predict(model,newdata=td[,-1])) #Erro here

newlevels=levels(td$w)[!levels(td$w)%in%levels(d$w)]
ntd=td
ntd$w=factor(ifelse(td$w%in%newlevels,NA,td$w),labels=levels(d$w))
cbind(td$o,predict(model,newdata=ntd[,-1]))

        [,1]      [,2]
1  10.759956        NA
2   9.914360        NA
3   9.871389  9.598080
4  14.105807 10.192217
5   9.322687 10.207865
6  14.549412  9.524874
7   5.353742 10.258272
8  11.753841 10.180756
9  10.371563  9.451669
10 10.647825 10.324328
```

Comment: As I mentioned the training data I do not have :) The problem was about the class of the variables, as I have posted in the answer. :) Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: Ok, I started using your idea, but with some replacements, I have `ntd[factorName] = factor(ifelse(unlist(tstData[factorName]) %in% newlevels, NA, unlist(tstData[factorName])), labels = levels(unlist(factorValues)))` that gives the following error: `Error in factor(ifelse(unlist(tstData[factorName]) %in% newlevels, NA, : invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1` Can you help me solving it?

Comment: I think it is linked to the fact that I have not all the factors in the testing data...

Answer (score 1):

you can use ifelse to replace the values conditionally with NA

```
newvar = ifelse(oldvar=="new levels",NA,oldvar)
```

Comment: how to do it, if I cannot get the unkown values? I do not know "new levels", how to get the new levels?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `factorValues` was a list, the `%in%` was not working, and the `as.factor` was also returning an error because the list was sorted (at leas that is what it seems). So to transform a list in factor, `unlist` shall be called. The problem is now solved:

```
knownData <- subset(allData, allData[,factorName] %in% factorValues)
```

There was another problem: `factorName` was of class character, so there was always 1 `FALSE` returned from `%in%`